# WordPress Contact form 7 Will the dynamically set hidden field values be sent to email on submit

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Currently I don't possess a web server. I just want to know if the hidden fields in "Contact Form 7" WordPress plugin will send the dynamically added values (through jQuery syntax like `$("#calculated_total").val(total);`) using jQuery to the recipient email on submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the hidden field in the form design and have a jQuery function that updates the value, you can then add the field shortcode to the recipient email. I've used this to dynamically populate a hidden field with the page URL and send that via email:

**On the form:**

```
[hidden calculated_total id:calculated_total]
```

Then all you need to is include the line below in the recipient email:

**On any email:**

```
Calculated Total: [calculated_total]
```